# how can we share events accross multipe task panes in office.js?

Tags: office365, office-js

i am creating office web add-in using office.js, i've a requirement to share events between multiple taskpanes.

Problem: -
when user selects something in one taskpane, i want to show pdf on another taskpane.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you.

Comment: Without sufficient detail explaining your exact scenario, all I can suggest is to use local storage to communicate between your taskpanes.

Comment: @SameerSingh i've two task pane. in one taskpane i show some data in tree fromat & when user clicks on data i show related information in second pane. is there some way i can programmatically open task pane in Office.js.

Comment: @SameerSingh i've solved the problem using  Office.context.document.settings. i'm setting values in document settings & getting in another pane. if you know other solution then please share.

Comment: @RahulBisht I don't think you can programmatically open a taskpane. You can however [auto-open one (and only one) taskpane on document open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document?product=word).

Answer (score 0):

Office add-ins are designed to be worked in sandbox. As a result, each of them are separated from each other. If you want listen to the same event, you can register to the same event type from both of the add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

Because all instances of your addin are hosted on the same url, they share one localstorage.

Listen for changes:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {  
   console.log("Localstorage changed!");
});
```

Commit changes:

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
```

Documentation:

- [Using the Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)
- [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)